# React Native application with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, react-native, stored-procedures

In my React Native application, I encountered an issue with the code after the user enters the correct email and password. If the user is a teacher and has an IDCours equal to 0, they should be redirected to a new screen called 'AjouterCours' for adding a course. The problem arises when the user inputs the data (course name and chapter names). The IDCours is only stored in the 'chapitre' and 'cours' tables, but it remains null in the 'enseignant' table's 'IDCours' column, even though IDCours is a foreign key.

this is file registre.php :

```
// Set the response header to JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Get the request body
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Decode the request body to an object
$request_data = json_decode($request_body);

// Check if the required fields exist in the request object
if (!isset($request_data->Email) || !isset($request_data->Mot_de_Passe)) {
  $response = [
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Adresse e-mail ou mot de passe manquant'
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}

// Get the email and password from the request object
$Email = $request_data->Email;
$Mot_de_Passe = $request_data->Mot_de_Passe;

// Connect to the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$db_password = ""; // Change this to your actual database password
$dbname = "cstt";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check if the user exists in enseignant table
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM enseignant WHERE Email = ? AND Mot_de_Passe = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $Email, $Mot_de_Passe);
$stmt->execute();
$result_e = $stmt->get_result();

// If the user exists in enseignant table and IDCours=0, redirect to "ajouterCours" screen
if ($result_e->num_rows === 1) {
  $row = $result_e->fetch_assoc();
  $Nom_Prenom = $row['Nom_Prenom'];
  $IDCour = $row['IDCours'];

  if ($IDCour == 0) {
    $response = [
      'status' => 'success',
      'message' => 'Bienvenue chers enseignant',
      'screen' => 'AjouterCours',
      'Nom_Prenom' => $row['Nom_Prenom'] // Set the Nom_Prenom field here
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
    // Write the value of $Nom_Prenom to the PHP error log for debugging
error_log('Nom_Prenom value: ' . $Nom_Prenom);


    exit;
  }
  
  // If IDCours is not equal to 0, redirect to "Enseignant_C" screen
else {
  $Nom_Prenom = $row['Nom_Prenom'];
  // Write the value of $Nom_Prenom to the PHP error log for debugging
  error_log('Nom_Prenom value: ' . $Nom_Prenom);

  $response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Bienvenue chers enseignant',
    'screen' => 'Enseignant_C',
    'Nom_Prenom' => $Nom_Prenom // Set the Nom_Prenom field here
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}

}


// If the user does not exist in enseignant table, check if the user exists in etudiant table
else {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM etudiant WHERE Email = ? AND Mot_de_Passe = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $Email, $Mot_de_Passe);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result_s = $stmt->get_result();

  // If the user exists in etudiant table, return the screen name "Etudiant" and welcome message for etudiant
  if ($result_s->num_rows === 1) {
    $response = [
      'status' => 'success',
      'message'=>      'Bienvenue chers etudiants',
      'screen' => 'Etudiant'
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
  }
}

// Check if the user exists in administrateur table
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM administrateur WHERE Email = ? AND Mot_de_Passe = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $Email, $Mot_de_Passe);
$stmt->execute();
$result_a = $stmt->get_result();

// If the user exists in administrateur table, return the screen name "Administrateur" and welcome message for administrateur
if ($result_a->num_rows === 1) {
  $response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Bienvenue chers Administrateur',
    'screen' => 'Administrateur'
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}

// If the user does not exist in any table, return an error message
$response = [
  'status' => 'error',
  'message' => 'Adresse e-mail ou mot de passe invalide'
];

// Close the prepared statement and database connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

// Return the response as JSON
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and this is file login.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert ,Image} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Picker from "react-native-picker";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Background from "./Background";



const LoginScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [Mot_de_Passe, setMot_de_Passe] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.15/api/registre.php', {
        Email,
        Mot_de_Passe,
      });
  
      const responseData = response.data;
      if (responseData.status === 'success') {
        Alert.alert('Success', responseData.message);
        switch (responseData.screen) {
          case 'Enseignant_C':
            navigation.navigate('Enseignant_C');//if user is teacher
            break;
          case 'AjouterCours':
            navigation.navigate('Enseignant');//pour ajouter un cours (first login)
            break;
          case 'Etudiant':
            navigation.navigate('Etudiant');//if the user is student
            break;
            case 'Administrateur':
              navigation.navigate('Administrateur');
              break;
          default:
            // If the screen value is not recognized, show an error message
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Invalid screen value');
            break;
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', responseData.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'An error occurred while logging in. Please try again later.');
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <Background>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Image
          source={require('../src/imgs/logoApp.png')}
          style={{width: 200,
            height: 150,
        alignSelf:'center'}}
        />
      <TextInput
      style={{borderRadius: 100, color:'red', paddingHorizontal:3, width: '90%',height: '5%', backgroundColor: 'rgb(220,220, 220)', marginVertical: 10}}
      placeholder="Email"
        value={Email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
      />
      <TextInput
      style={{borderRadius: 100, color:'red', paddingHorizontal:3, width: '90%',height: '5%', backgroundColor: 'rgb(220,220, 220)', marginVertical: 10}}
      placeholder="Mot de passe"
        value={Mot_de_Passe}
        onChangeText={setMot_de_Passe}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{  backgroundColor:"#000324",
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        borderRadius: 30,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 300,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginVertical: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        overflow: 'hidden',}}
        onPress={handleLogin}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Connexion</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00fa00" />
    </View>
    </Background>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

and this is file AjouterCours.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View , Button ,Image , TouchableOpacity}  from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import Background from "./Background";
import axios from 'axios';
import Btn from './Btn';

const AjouterCours = () => {
  const [NomCours, setNomCours] = useState('');
  const [NumChapitre, setNumChapitre] = useState(1);
  const [NomChapitres, setNomChapitres] = useState(['']);

  const handleNumChapitreChange = (value) => {
    const num = parseInt(value);
    setNumChapitre(num);
    setNomChapitres(new Array(num).fill(''));
  };

  const handleNomChapitreChange = (value, index) => {
    const names = [...NomChapitres];
    names[index] = value;
    setNomChapitres(names);
  };


  const insert = () => {
    console.log("Data to be sent:", data);

    if (NomCours.length === 0 ) {
      alert('Champ obligatoire manquant');
      return;
    }

    const data = {
      NomCours: NomCours,
      NomChapitre: NomChapitres,
      NumChapitre: NumChapitre, 
    };
    
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    
    axios.post('http://192.168.1.15/api/AjouterCours.php', data, { headers })
    
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Data to be sent:", data);

        if (response.data && response.data[0] && response.data[0].Message) {
          alert(response.data[0].Message);
        } else {
          alert('Error: No response from server');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error:", error);

        console.log('Error:', error);
        if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
          alert('Error: Unable to connect to server');
        } else if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data[0] && error.response.data[0].Message) {
          alert(error.response.data[0].Message);
        } else {
          alert('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
      });
  };


  const renderChapitreInputs = () => {
    const inputs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NumChapitre; i++) {
      const input = (
        <TextInput
          key={i}
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={`Nom du chapitre ${i + 1}`}
          value={NomChapitres?.[i]}
          onChangeText={(text) => handleNomChapitreChange(text, i)}
        />
      );
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    return inputs;
  };




  return (
    <Background>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
          source={require('../src/imgs/logoApp.png')}
          style={{width: 200,
            height: 150,
            marginTop:20,
        alignSelf:'center'}}
        />
        <Text style={styles.title}>  </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Nom du cours"
          value={NomCours}
          onChangeText={(text) => setNomCours(text)}
        />
        <Picker
          style={styles.picker}
          selectedValue={NumChapitre.toString()}
          onValueChange={(value) => handleNumChapitreChange(value)}
        >
          {[...Array(10)].map((_, i) => (
            <Picker.Item key={i} label={`${i + 1}`} value={`${i + 1}`} />
          ))}
        </Picker>
        {renderChapitreInputs()}
        <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={insert}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "#000324",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 300,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  }}
>
  
<Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Enregistrer</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    </Background>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#ff7f50',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    textShadowColor:'white'
  },
  picker: {
    borderRadius: 1000,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    color:'blue',
    paddingHorizontal:3,
    width: '50%',
    height: '5%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(220,220, 220)',
    marginVertical: 10
  },
});

export default AjouterCours;
```

and this is file AjouterCour.php:

```
<?php
// Print out the data that is being received
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);

// Connect to the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cstt";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Get the course name and chapter list from the input data
$NomCours = isset($data['NomCours']) ? $data['NomCours'] : '';
$NomChapitres = isset($data['NomChapitre']) ? $data['NomChapitre'] : array();
$NumChapitre = isset($data['NumChapitre']) ? $data['NumChapitre'] : '';

// Create the SQL query to insert the data into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO cours (Nom, chapitres) VALUES ('$NomCours', '$NumChapitre')";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO enseignant (NomCours) VALUES ('$NomCours')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
    echo "New course record created successfully. ";

    // Retrieve the auto-generated ID of the inserted row
    $idCours = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    // Insert the chapter names into the 'chapitres' table
    foreach ($NomChapitres as $NomChapitre) {
        $NomChapitre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $NomChapitre);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO chapitres (Nom, IDCours) VALUES ('$NomChapitre', '$idCours')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New chapter record created successfully. ";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }

    // Update the 'IDCours' and 'NomCours' columns in the 'enseignant' table for the newly added record
    $sql = "UPDATE enseignant SET IDCours = '$idCours', NomCours = '$NomCours' WHERE IDCours = $idCours";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "IDCours and NomCours updated successfully in the enseignant table.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I think your issue with maintaining the value, that need to pass on, just make sure all value is available before posting, and you not using transaction, for multiple query eg insert, the record might not consistent in the future.